# show multiple values from the data array in multiple HTML table elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to show multiple values from the data array in multiple HTML table elements at once. And the data value going to change and it needs to be overwritten in HTML. I tried something like below by using nested `forEach` but it doesn't work. What should I do?

I've tried `appendchild` but it creates new cells as the data value renewed and I don't want it.

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>something</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="changeThis">
      <th>row head</th>
      <td>0</td><!-- 1 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- 2 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- 3 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- 4 -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

js

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const changeThis = document.querySelector("#changeThis");

changeThis.forEach(cellItem => {
   data.forEach(dataItem => {
      cellItem.innerHTML = dataItem
   })
})
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you mean `appendChild` instead of `appendchild`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to select all tds and add your content

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const changeThis = document.querySelectorAll("#changeThis td");


changeThis.forEach((cellItem,idx) => {
      cellItem.innerHTML = data[idx];
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>something</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="changeThis">
      <th>row head</th>
      <td>0</td><!-- 1 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- 2 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- 3 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- 4 -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do that...

```js
const 
  data       = [1, 2, 3, 4]
, changeThis = document.querySelector('#changeThis')
  ;
let index = 0;

for (let cell of [...changeThis.cells])
  {
  if ( cell.matches('td'))
     cell.textContent = data[index++]
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>something</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="changeThis">
      <th>row head</th>
      <td>0</td><!-- 1 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- 2 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- 3 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- 4 -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```